# Any possible way to start geofencing with Mapbox SDK for Android

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I got severel points on my map and i would like to notify the user when he is within a 1km radius to a point. But i couldn't find a solution or example for this with the Mapbox SDK.

Is there another (easy) way to do this as a beginner?

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-location-listening/ shows how you can track a user's location with the Maps SDK for Android.

Every time you get a location update, you can run a calculation to determine whether the device's location is within 1km to the destination `Point`.

This calculation can be done many ways depending on whether the distance is straight line, how you want to visualize the distance, etc.

There's the `within` and `distance` expressions

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/examples/turf-circle-poi-within-filter/

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/examples/turf-physical-circle/

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/examples/turf-line-distance/

A simple Directions API call https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/examples/show-directions-on-a-map